# How to get a query to return certain records based on the total

Tags: sql-server

I got a recordset looking like this:

```
Group Number   Amount
A     11        10
A     12        -15
A     13        20
B     21        -10
B     22        15
B     23        -20
```

What I want is a query to return all lines within a group if the total amount of that group is larger zero
For Group A, the total is 15, hence I want all records with group A return.
For Group B, the total is -15, so no records should be returned from group B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SUM` with `OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  clause to accomplish this:

```
SELECT [Group], Number, Amount
FROM (
   SELECT [Group], Number, Amount,
          SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group]) AS sumOfGroup
   FROM mytable ) t
WHERE t.sumOfGroup > 0
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68f35/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     select * from yourTable where [Group] in
     (select [Group] from yourTable group by [Group] having SUM(Amount) > 0)
```

Comment: this will be the simplest solution